# AWS Load Balancer : redirection based on path but strip the path

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, aws-application-load-balancer

Given I have two configurations in AWS Load Balancer:

- https://payments.domain.com
- https://all.domain.com

I would like to add a rule which redirect https://all.domain.com/payments/* to https://payments.domain.com/*

I am able to create conditions on host and path (/payments/*), but I am not able to remove "/payments" from the path while redirecting.

In other words, how could I rewrite /#{path} to remove "/payments" ?

Comment: I don't think it's going to be possible to remove part of the path, while retaining the rest of the path, in a load balancer redirect rule. There is no way to do any sort of string substitution or anything of that sort inside an ALB listener rule.

Comment: OK thanks to confirm what I thought. So, you suggest to use a reverse proxy for that case ?